# How to put an event on the buttons of QMessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I just want to set an event on the yes button of the message box but when I click the yes button it returns me None value and it not satisfies the condition.

```
def question(self):
    msg = QMessageBox()
    result = msg.setStandardButtons(msg.Yes | msg.No)
    msg.setIcon(msg.Question)
    msg.setText(self.text)
    msg.setWindowTitle('Console')

    if result == msg.Yes:
        print('Yes')

    msg.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setStandardButtons()` is a setter and returns nothing, the logic is actually to get the button clicked and then get the associated `QMessageBox::StandardButton`.

```
def question(self):
    msg = QMessageBox()
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    msg.setIcon(msg.Question)
    msg.setText(self.text)
    msg.setWindowTitle('Console')
    msg.exec_()
    button = msg.clickedButton()
    sb = msg.standardButton(button)
    if sb == QMessageBox.Yes:
        print("YES")
```

Comment: Thank you for the new knowledge!